# Link to a constantly changing link

Tags: html

Is there any way to link to a page whose link changes on a weekly basis?

example:

- site.com/4-1-13_page
- site.com/4-8-13_page
- site.com/4-15-13_page
- site.com/4-22-13_page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a server-side language like PHP, you can [generate the link based on the current date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). For instance:

```
$day = intval(date('j'));
// Normalize to the start of a week
if ($day % 7 > 0) {
    $day -= (%day % 7);
}
$month = date('n');
$year = date('y');
$link = "site.com/" . $day . "-" . $month . "-" . $year . "_page";
```

If you're serving a static page, you can do the same with Javascript but it will depend on the user system clock being accurate. A simple implementation:

```
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDate() - date.getDay(); // getDay() returns an
                                          //   integer in the range 0-6
var month = date.getMonth() + 1; // getMonth() returns in range 0-11
var year = date.getFullYear().toString().slice(2); // getFullYear() returns 
                                                   //   a 4-digit year
var link = "site.com/" + day + "-" + month + "-" + year + "_page";
```

There are very likely to be edge cases you will need to work out when adapting this code, but it should be sufficient to get you started.

Comment: Thanks Jared. What search terms would I use to go the JS route?

Answer (score 0):

If using PHP:

```
<?php
    $startingDate = strtotime('2013-04-01');
    echo '<a href="site.com/' . date('n-j-y', $startingDate) . '_page">Link text</a>';
?>
```

If using JavaScript:

```
var startingDate = new Date(2013, 4, 1);
var day = startingDate.getDate();
var month = startingDate.getMonth() + 1;
var year = startingDate.getFullYear().toString().substr(2, 2);
document.write('<a href="site.com/' + month + '-' + day + '-' + year + '_page">Link text</a>');
```